# Efficient BigDecimal round Up and down to two decimals

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

In java am trying to find an efficient way to round a BigDecimal to two decimals, Up or Down based on a condition.

```
 IF condition true then:
    12.390 ---> 12.39
    12.391 ---> 12.40
    12.395 ---> 12.40
    12.399 ---> 12.40

 If condition false then:
    12.390 ---> 12.39
    12.391 ---> 12.39
    12.395 ---> 12.39
    12.399 ---> 12.39
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you just going to convert it into a string or display it, or are you going to use it in some other way?

Comment: It is being passed to a third party library method that takes a BigDecimal.  The library will then take the value and add it to a string message.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal d, int scale, boolean roundUp) {
  int mode = (roundUp) ? BigDecimal.ROUND_UP : BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN;
  return d.setScale(scale, mode);
}
round(new BigDecimal("12.390"), 2, true); // => 12.39
round(new BigDecimal("12.391"), 2, true); // => 12.40
round(new BigDecimal("12.391"), 2, false); // => 12.39
round(new BigDecimal("12.399"), 2, false); // => 12.39
```

Comment: The mode should be RoundingMode.FLOOR and RoundingMode.CEILING instead of BigDecimal.ROUND_UP and BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN.

Answer (score 2):

```
num = num.setScale(condition ? RoundingMode.UP : RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

But note that your spec is not entirely clear when it comes to negative numbers. Take a look at the various rounding modes in the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) and see what exactly you need.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following (standing on the shoulders of giants...):

```
public BigDecimal roundNumber(final BigDecimal number, final boolean isFloor){
     return number.setScale(2, isFloor ? RoundingMode.FLOOR 
                                       : RoundingMode.CEILING);
}
```