# Rounding method in Java equivalent to SQL Server rounding

Tags: java, sql-server, rounding

I'm using a `BigDecimal` variable in my application calculation. In some cases when the `Bigdecimal` value is 2.9922 and I save data to SQL Server 2012, I get a 2.99 record in DB. Such rounding is OK for me but sometimes I need to compare records in the DB with a new calculation and I need them to have same rounding method.

So my question is what is the rounding method in Java that will be identical to SQL server 2012 rounding method?

Is it `BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN` or `BigDecimal.ROUND_UP`, `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` or which one?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for each of those options?

Answer (score -1):

So basically it you want to deal with Scale in decimal values.
For this : if you can change the decimal scale of your data column in db. 
for example : like if you column name is-->  [value] DECIMAL(15,2)--> you can change that to [value] DECIMAL(15,5) by using alter table script.

Because BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN or BigDecimal.ROUND_UP is satisfying the different use case.

which you can refer gere You can control the scale from java as mentioned here.
[Efficient BigDecimal round Up and down to two decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681868/efficient-bigdecimal-round-up-and-down-to-two-decimals)

Thanks

Comment: I don't need changes in DB. I need to change code to get the same rounded values as in my DB.